# javascript- Traffic lights, my images will not show on the html

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var lights=["Images/nt1.jpg","Images/nt2.jpg","Images/nt3.jpg","Images/nt4.png"]
      var lightscentre= 0
      var timer
      function LightCycle
      {
        if(++lightscentre==30)
          lightscentre=0

          document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

          timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000)
      }
      function stopCycle()
      {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="nt1.jpg" name="nt1" width=130 height=175>

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="LightCycle()">
      <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my code, I can't get the images to show only the buttons, All I can see is a box with a black cross, please help me see the error, as I need the images to know if the code works. Background; this is code showing the sequence of traffic lights that should loop continuously when the window is opened. P.S the code doesn't normally look like this it just happened when I pasted it in.

Comment: What is `document.images.banner`?

Comment: use "function LightCycle()" instead of "function LightCycle"

Comment: and the correct way to declare setTimeout function is:  `setTimeout(LightCycle,1000)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidied version of your code:

```
var lights = ["Images/nt1.jpg", "Images/nt2.jpg", "Images/nt3.jpg", "Images/nt4.png"]
var lightscentre = 0
var timer

function LightCycle() {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    if (++lightscentre == lights.length)
        lightscentre = 0

    document.images[0].src = lights[lightscentre]

    timer = setTimeout(LightCycle, 1000)
}

function stopCycle() {
    clearTimeout(timer)
}
```

What I have changed:

- When declaring your function, you need `()` after the function name, if no parameters are used.
- I cleared any existing timers at the start of `LightCycle`, so that pressing the button twice will not lead to the cycle going twice as fast.
- I changed the method of selecting the image: you may have a different method in your full code, but `document.images.banner` doesn't mean anything as far as I know.
- I simplified the setTimeout call: a function name is faster than a string to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes:

```
1 function LightCycle 
2 {
3     if(++lightscentre==30) {
4       lightscentre=0
5     }
6     document.images[0].src = lights[lightscentre]
7 
8     timer = setTimeout(LightCycle, 1000)
9 }
```

- Line 1: Use correct function declaration
- Line 6: This works on the first image found in the document. If there will be more images you have to adjust the images index dynamically.
- Line 8: You can pass the `LightCycle` function as an argument to `setTimeout` without quoting it. Especially as it `LightCycle` does not take any arguments itself.

.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in your code, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lights = ["Images/nt1.jpg","Images/nt2.jpg","Images/nt3.jpg","Images/nt4.png"];
        var lightscentre= 0
        var timer
        function lightCycle()
        {
            if(++lightscentre==3)
                lightscentre=0;

            document.getElementsByName("nt1")[0].src = lights[lightscentre]

            timer = setTimeout(lightCycle,1000)
        }
        function stopCycle()
        {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="nt1.jpg" name="nt1" width=130 height=175>
        <form>
        <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="lightCycle()">
        <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Working Code should Look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lights=["Images/nt1.jpg","Images/nt2.jpg","Images/nt3.jpg","Images/nt4.png"]
    var lightscentre= 0;
    var timer;
    function LightCycle()
    {
      if(++lightscentre==4)
        lightscentre=0

      document.getElementById("nt1").setAttribute("src",lights[lightscentre]);
      timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000);
    }
    function stopCycle()
    {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="nt1.jpg" name="nt1" id="nt1" width=130 height=175>

<form>
  <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="LightCycle()">
  <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```